# ExtJS: How do I bind a label to a ViewModel store with a Single record

Tags: extjs, data-binding, viewmodel

Please see the following Fiddle: [Bind store from a ViewModel to an xtype label](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/25c6&view/editor)

I am NOT able to get the record from my ViewModel's store to display in the `xtype: 'label'` item of my form.

This should be easy, but alas my brain is not able to work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to create a bind descriptor for the first record of a store. You will need to implement a [formula](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.app.bind.Formula.html) for this purpose.

In your view model:

```
formulas: {
    firstTestStoreRecord: {
        bind: '{testStore}',
        get: function(testStore) {
            return testStore.getAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this in your view:

```
bind: {
    html: '<b>{firstTestStoreRecord.test}</b>'
}
```

Here is the working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/25cf&view/editor

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: @scebotari66 "There is no way to create a bind descriptor for the first record of a store" FYI this is no longer true as of 6.5: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/25ck&view/editor

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You can bind to first/last/count/totalCount. You can also bind to model dirty/phantom/valid too, newly added to 6.5.

Answer (score 1):

In version 7.4:

```
bind: {
    html: '<b>{testStore.first.test}</b>'
}
```